# Problems while rendering with Atlas

Tags: openlayers-2, rendering, atlas

when I export my data genereated with the openLayers using Atlas rendering is always incomplete. Atlas is rendering too fast so that the data from openLayers is not completely loaded.

Do anyone knows how to handle this?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

The OpenLayers plugin really hasn't been designed to work with QGIS' map composer. There's some workarounds which make it partially usable, but nothing robust and its prone to errors like these. See http://hub.qgis.org/issues/8824, http://hub.qgis.org/issues/5827