# QGIS Atlas web layer rendering - how can I slow it down?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, rendering, cache, atlas

I cannot get Atlas to export maps with web layers correctly.

When I look at the preview within composer everything works fine.
When I export an atlas the first page renders ok but for subsequent pages only a couple of tiles are usually generated.

My suspicion is that QGIS is rendering faster than the web layers can be downloaded.

I suggest that if it is possible to slow down the rendering process this will allow time for tiles to download.

I have no idea how to do this but maybe a developer can tell me how to slow down the Atlas rendering process to allow for tile downloads?

A similar question has been raised before on the GIS SE as [Problems while rendering with Atlas](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112181/problems-while-rendering-with-atlas).

My question is not the same because I am looking for a way to either test out my hypothesis or for somebody to tell me that my hypothesis completely wrong.

Comment: The answer to that question already answer this one, i.e the OpenLayers plugin doesn't work well with the composer.

Comment: I have already referenced that question in my post. In the last sentence I explain that my question is about slowing down the rendering process to allow sufficient time for tiles to download. Then I think it would work. I imagine for a developer this is a feasible change to try...